# Gradle dependencies: How to figure out what's causing this duplication

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have an Android project which contains a `MultiDex` application.

I am trying to run Espresso tests using `./gradlew clean connectectedAndroidTest`. This command ultimately results in this error message:

```
:app:dexDebugAndroidTest
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry;
```

My top-level `build.gradle` contains:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

and I use Gradle 2.4 via the wrapper.

My project's `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
//        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'

            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources = false
            zipAlignEnabled = false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            shrinkResources = true
            zipAlignEnabled = true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // Auth0
    compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:lock-googleplus:1.7.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.1'

    // Robolectric
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0-rc3" // otherwise robolectric tests fail on MultiDex.install

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
        exclude module: 'testing-support-lib'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    }

}

robolectric {
    // Configure includes / excludes
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'

    // Configure max heap size of the test JVM
    maxHeapSize = '2048m'

    // Configure the test JVM arguments - Does not apply to Java 8
    //jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=512m', '-XX:-UseSplitVerifier'

    // Specify max number of processes (default is 1)
    maxParallelForks = 4

    // Specify max number of test classes to execute in a test process
    // before restarting the process (default is unlimited)
    forkEvery = 150

    // configure whether failing tests should fail the build
    ignoreFailures true

    // use afterTest to listen to the test execution results
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        println "Executing test for ${descriptor.name} with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
```

Now I've been trying to figure out what's going on, for example by looking at the dependencies using `./gradlew -q app:dependencies` which results in (among other internal configurations):

```
androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.4.201502262128
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128


androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.2
|         +--- junit:junit-dep:4.10
|         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
|         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.2
+--- com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0
     +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
     +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.0
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
     +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1


compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.auth0.android:lock:1.7.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 -> 22.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1
|    +--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.5
|    +--- com.auth0.android:identity-core:1.7.0
|    |    +--- com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2 -> 22.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.auth0.android:core:1.7.0
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1
|    |         +--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1
|    |              +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0 -> 2.4.1
|    |              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1
|    \--- com.auth0.android:core:1.7.0 (*)
+--- com.auth0.android:lock-googleplus:1.7.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2 -> 22.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.auth0.android:identity-core:1.7.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.87 -> 7.3.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0 -> 22.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0 (*)
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.4
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.1
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.1
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.3.1
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.1 (*)
\--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.1
     \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.1 (*)


testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
+--- org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3
|    +--- junit:junit:4.8.2
|    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3
|    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.0-rc3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0-rc3
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:1.0
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3
|    |    \--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
|    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0-rc3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:shadows-core:3.0-rc3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0-rc3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.0-rc3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:53.1
|    |    \--- com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:0.282
|    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.1
|    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1
|    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.0.1
|    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
|    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.1
|    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
|    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0
|         \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.0
\--- org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0-rc3
     \--- org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3 (*)
```

Now my question is, how do I go about figuring out what is causing the duplication? From what I understand it should be some library that is including another library that is defining `InstrumentationRegistry`.

Comment: If you are not using at least android gradle plugin 1.1.1, then I suggest you to upgrade because it provide more explicit information about conflicting dependencies.  buildscript {...    dependencies{classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1' ...  }}

Comment: @ben75 I am using 1.2.3 (I updated the question to specify it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Espresso 2.1 [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/ReleaseNotes):

*"...test runner artifact split into two and the name changed from com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1 to com.android.support.test:runner:0.2 + com.android.support.test:rules:0.2..."*

In your dependencies you are mixing two test runners by including old testing-support-lib and new rules.

So you either switch entirely to the new test runner by adding a runner:0.2 dependency instead of the old support-lib or opt out of using rules.

If you want to keep the rules in, your androidTest dependencies will look something like this:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
    exclude module: 'testing-support-lib'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
```